# Can a control verb simultaneously be a raising verb?

Tags: syntax, verbs, control, raising

For example, take *believes*, which is a raising to object verb.
However, employing various selection tests, you can observe that *believes* selects an experiencer subject:

> #the cat believes to be out of the bag
>       *there believes to be a lot of hens here
>       *it believes to be raining

In these tests *believes* seems to select a specific subject because it rejects instances of tight selection (idioms) and existential there. This behavior is much like subject control verbs, like *wants*.

However, given the tests in object position:

> ?# Harold believes the cat to be out of the bag
>          Harold believes there to be a lot of hens here
>          Harold believes it to be raining

We see that *believes* doesn't seem to select for a specific object, which would leave us to presume it is a raising to object verb.

Does this mean that *believes* is both subject control and object raising?

NOTE: This is assuming the VP internal subject hypothesis.

Comment: Can you please edit to add the reasoning behind the tests and how it leads you to the question?

Comment: Yes, the subject of "believe" works differently than the object of "believe", but what does the one thing have to do with the other?  I don't understand the question.

Comment: Here's my question phrased differently: if you can apply selection tests to determine that (1) "believe" selects for a subject, and (2) "believe" does not select for an object, is the verb "believe" both subject control (because of (1)) and raising to obj (because of (2))?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, or at least not *believe* in English. *Control* is a relation between an argument of the matrix clause and a (big) PRO in the embedded one, which supplies the PRO with reference.

In examples with *believe*, the trace left after raising to object seems to be the only (relevant) empty category in the sentence:

(1) I [believe [the cat]<sub>i</sub> [t<sub>i</sub> to be out of the bag].

Answer (score 1):

Well, not ***simultaneously***, no. Not in the same sentence.

But as [these exercises](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) makes clear, it **can** happen that a particular English verb, like *want*,

governs Equi (aka "Equivalent Noun Phrase Deletion" and "*Control*") in one context,

- *Bill wants ___to leave.*
  *Bill wants to be examined by the doctor.*
  ≠ *The doctor wants to examine Bill.*

and Raising (aka "Subject-Raising") in another.

- *Bill wants Max to leave*.
  *Bill wants [it to rain/there to be a party].*
  *Bill wants Max to be examined by the doctor.
  = Bill wants the doctor to examine Max.*
  [**NB**: *want* does not passivize Raised objects:
  **Max is wanted to leave by Bill*. ]

Essentially, English *want* governs A-Equi when it meets the conditions
   (coreferential subjects of both *want* and its complement clause)
but governs B-Raising when it **doesn't** meet the conditions for A-Equi
   (complement subject not coreferential to the subject of *want*)

As for the classification of *believe*, the syntax lab reports from [these same exercises](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) list *believe* as

> 2-place with B-Raising (mental predicate, experiencer subject, propositional object).
>      [NB: *believe* may also passivize Raised objects on the next cycle up, producing a rule sandwich:
>                  e.g, *The men are believed to have been seen by the women* ]

As @Ivan has pointed out, if a verb selects a particular type of subject, that is not the same as,
and makes no prediction about, whether that verb governs Equivalent Noun Phrase Deletion.

By the way, this is not a question about syntax so much it is about **English** syntax --
be aware that things can work very differently in different languages.